# Navigation.navigate does not reset route params - React native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have a list of objects. I'm passing the selected item to another screen now in that screen. I'm pushing details of object, now going back to previous screen, and again navigate to same screen. That time I'm still getting previous selected item data which I previously selected in the list. How to reset navigation params data?

**Screen 1:**

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onLongPress={() => {
    setSelectedItem(item.TypeofPlant)
    createTwoButtonAlert()
  }} 
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Screen2', { item: item.Nameplan })}
>
```

**Screen 2:**

```
const { item } = route.params
const isMounted = useRef(true)

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
       fetchData();
    }
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    }
  }, [])

  const fetchData = () => {
    console.log(item);
         
    DataService.getPlantByType(item)
      .then((responseJson) => responseJson)
      .then((response) => {
        setItems(response.data);
       
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error)
      })
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The item selected always keeps the first selected one - React native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72229858/the-item-selected-always-keeps-the-first-selected-one-react-native)

Comment: yeah I removed the question because there are no responses & comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use dispatch CommonAction with reset-action to clear back-stack of my application, so that application go back to previous screen when user press hardware reset-button :

```
<Button
    title="Reset navigation state"
    onPress={() =>
      navigation.dispatch(
        CommonActions.reset({
          index: 1,
          routes: [
            {
              name: 'Screen 2',
              params: {key: route.params.key },
            },
            { name: 'Screen 1' },
          ],
        })
      )
    }
  />
```